# A limit question involving Cramer's decomposition of normal random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I've come across the following question. Say we have two families of random variables, $X_N$ and $Y_N$, such that $\mathbb{E} X_N=\mathbb{E} Y_N=0$ and $\mathbb{E}X_N^2=1$. Now assume that:
$$|\mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X_N}\mathbb{E} e^{\lambda Y_N}e^{-a_N^2\lambda^2/2}-1|\to 0$$
uniformly on bounded compact sets of $\mathbb{C}$. My question is whether from this you can conclude that $X_N\Rightarrow \cal{N}(0,1)$?

If $a_N^2$ is bounded this follows from Cramer's decomposition theorem, but I cannot either prove or disprove the statement in the case where $a_N^2$ is unbounded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I'll sketch the proof when $a_N^2$ is bounded. It suffices to show that any subsequence of $X_N$ has a further subsequence that converges in measure to $\cal{N}(0,1)$. As $a_N^2$ is bounded, we may pass to a subsequence such that $a_N^2\to a^2$ for some $a$. On the other hand this shows that the characteristic functions of $X_N+Y_N$ converges to $e^{-a^2\lambda^2/2}$, and so by Levy's continuity theorem, we have that $X_N+Y_N\Rightarrow \cal{N}(0,a^2)$.

Now by Jensen's inequality we have that for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $1\le \mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X_N}$. Thus for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, we have that $|\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X_N}|\le \mathbb{E}e^{\Re(\lambda)X_N}\le e^{a_N^2\Re(\lambda)^2/2}$, so that $\mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X_N}$ is a locally uniformly bounded family of analytic functions, so by Montel's theorem, and passing to a subsequence, we can assume that $\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X_N}$ converges to some analytic function, which by the Levy continuity theorem, must be the moment-generating function of some random variable, say $X$, such that $X_N\Rightarrow X$ in distribution and in moments. One may do the same for $Y$.

Thus we see that $X+Y=\cal{N}(0,a^2)$. By Cramer's theorem we must have that $X$ is normal, and as by the moment assumptions on $X_N$, as well as the convergence in moments, we see that $X=\cal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: @MattF. I added what you suggested I think.

Comment: The proof sketch is helpful (and impressive), but it would help to add back the definition of $a_N^2$, which I think should be $\mathbb{E} Y_N^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This need not hold if $a_n$ is unbounded.  Take $X_n$ to be Rademacher, i.e. $P(X_n = 1) = P(X_n = -1) = 1/2$.  Take $Y_n \sim N(0,n)$ and $a_n = \sqrt{n}$.  Then $$\left| \mathbb{E} e^{\lambda X_n} \mathbb{E} e^{\lambda Y_n} e^{-a_n^2 \lambda^2 / 2} - 1\right| = 
\left| \cosh(\lambda) - 1\right|$$
which is locally uniformly bounded for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah, I apologize, I made a mistake while editing the question last night. I meant to write $\|\mathbb{E} e^{-\lambda X_N}\mathbb{E} e^{\lambda Y_N} e^{-a_N^2\lambda^2/2}-1\|=o(1)$ insted of $O(1)$. I apologize for the confusion. I believe the $O(1)$ statement is wrong even in the finite case with roughly your counterexample.